# Null value as an Integer

Tags: c#, console

Line 34 - if I don't pass a data at run time I get an exception

> Input string was not in a correct format

...but when I pass data I don't. Plus I thought I have converted the string into an integer value so why is the exception message saying input string?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: @Olivier I don't see what's wrong with this question, unless it's been edited since you wrote this message. The questioner gives their code, explains what's going wrong and what they expected, and asks why it's not working. It would have been better if they'd pasted their code instead of a screenshot, but other than that it's in the correct format.

Comment: _[Did you read the manual?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_)_

Comment: What's wrong with the question, ask @jimboweb ? The image provided instead of code is small and illisible... That's what's wrong: it is a screenshot and it has been downsized by half...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's happening?

You're getting the exception because 
`Console.Readline` always returns a string which you then pass to `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToInt32` throws an exception if an empty string is passed in.

This short sample demonstrates the problem you're hitting.

```
try {
    Convert.ToInt32(""); // Let's see how ToInt32 behaves for empty strings
} catch (Exception ex ) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()} -> {ex.Message}");
}
```

Output:

```
System.FormatException -> Input string was not in a correct format.
```

## Possible fix

Something like this should help.

```
var ageStr = Console.ReadLine();
int? age = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ageStr) 
  ? Int32.Parse(ageStr);
  : null;
```

---

Since you're working with user input `int.TryParse` may be a better candidate.

```
var ageStr = Console.ReadLine();
int age;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(ageStr, out age);

if( !success ) {
   Console.WriteLine($"'{ageStr}' is not an acceptable value for age.");
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't do anything to help the OP understand what the problem was.

Comment: I thought it did (with the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` part) but, I hear you and I expanded the answer.

Comment: Thank-you for update.  +1  Yes nothing wrong with your original _don't do that...do this_ answer but in this case OP wanted to know what the problem is - which you have now addressed.  Well done.   **Mods:** please delete this comment

Answer (score 0):

@tymtam's answer should solve your problem, but here's an explanation of what's going wrong. It's true that you made the `age` variable nullable. But the `Convert.ToInt32()` method was not designed to return `null` with an empty string; it expects the string to be in numeric format already.

The `Int32.TryParse()` method that tymtam suggested takes the `age` variable as an argument using the `out` keyword, which means it puts the value in `age` if it can and returns `true`. If the number isn't in numeric format it will return `false` and leave `age` as null.

Fyi, in the future when you provide your code, paste it into your answer with a space between it and the question. Then highlight the code and click the `{}` button above the input box so it will look like this:

```
//Here is some code...
```